# jQuery event looping

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm looking for a way to shrink this down. It'not anything special or unique but I feel the repetitive nature of the code could lend itself to a sleeker and more functional refactoring.

```
$.e = {
    doc: { ready:[], custom:[] },
    win: { scroll:[], scrollstart:[], scrollstop:[], load:[], resize:[], resizestart:[], resizestop:[], orientationchange:[] }
};


$(window).on({
    load:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.load.length; i++){ $.e.win.load[i](); }},
    scroll:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.scroll.length; i++){ $.e.win.scroll[i](); }},
    scrollstart:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.scrollstart.length; i++){ $.e.win.scrollstart[i](); }},
    scrollstop:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.scrollstop.length; i++){ $.e.win.scrollstop[i](); }},
    resize:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.resize.length; i++){ $.e.win.resize[i](); }},
    resizestart:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.resizestart.length; i++){ $.e.win.resizestart[i](); }},
    resizestop:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.resizestop.length; i++){ $.e.win.resizestop[i](); }},
    orientationchange:function(){for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win.orientationchange.length; i++){ $.e.win.orientationchange[i](); }}
});
```

Comment: What is `$.e` ?

Comment: $.e is a custom object that houses the arrays for the custom events. I've edited the posting to show more.
-------------
*NOTE: The reason for this custom $.e is because the admin dashboard I am working in is riddled with dom.ready, window.load and win.resize events I needed a way to separate and organize the previous logic from the refactored logic.

Comment: Took the solution below... added a concept that combines the concepts.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Comment: `$.each($.e.win, function(_k,_v){
    $(window).on(_k, function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < $.e.win[_k].length; i++){ $.e.win[_k][i](); };
    })
});`

Answer (score 1):

Use one event listener that propagates the event.
The correct collection of listeners in $.e.win is selected with `event.type`.

```
$.each($.e.win, function(eventName) {
  $(window).on(eventName, propagateEvent);
});

function propagateEvent(event) {
  var listeners = $.e.win[event.type];
  for (var i = 0; i < listeners.length; i++) {
    listeners[i].call(this, event);
  }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach, the events are defined as an array at the beginning of the document as a $.e variable.

Comment: @googabeast, in that case the event subscription may be shortened, see the updated answer.

Comment: I was also thinking of the same solution. Why not use `each` instead of `for`?.

Comment: @Tushar, because without ES2015 arrow syntax there's no gain in clarity